# Phonegap Framework7 Back Button not working

Tags: javascript, phonegap, html-framework-7

I'm creating an hybrid app with Phonegap and Framework7 (v1 i guess).

I've been trying to set the "android back button" to quit the app after the user confirms it, and i've been looking at some examples but i can't get this to work. I'm using this:

```
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    console.log("Device is ready!");

    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.notification.confirm("Tem a certeza que quer fechar a aplicação?", onConfirmExit, 'Pizzarte', 'Sim,Não');
    }, false);

    function onConfirmExit(button) {
        if (button == 2) { //If User select a No, then return back;
            return;
        } else {
            navigator.app.exitApp(); // If user select a Yes, quit from the app.
        }
    }

    var mySwiper = myApp.swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination'
    });

});
```

But when I click the back button on Android, nothing happens. And the strange thing is that if i'm previewing the app using the Phonegap app this will work. Only when i install the final app on my phone, this does not work.

Please help/suggest me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you have dialogs plugin installed in your app?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap Developer app is a Cordova app which includes all the core plugins and a few 3rd party ones.

Your problem is you are trying to use `cordova-plugin-dialogs` for the confirm prompt, but you don't have it installed, so it does nothing.

So install it with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
But could you tell me how to install it?

I've tried running that command with node in my src folder but i get an error. And i tried updating my config.xml file with this line: <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs"> but phonegap just deletes this line automatically.

Comment: It's already wrote in the anwser ==> `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`

Comment: I know that @jcesarmobile wrote the answer but i don't where to put it. I'm very noob in this things. This is the error: https://gyazo.com/843c192849026c37a7eab9ef818ef5fb

Comment: run it from Pizzarte folder, not from plugins folder

Comment: @jcesarmobile when i run it from Pizzarte folder, i get this error:
https://gyazo.com/23c6cd04b3955609f03307710ad658d2

Comment: try removing it first with `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-dialogs` and adding it again. Or `cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.dialogs`. Looks like you have something already preventing from installing correctly. Or even try with `rm -rf platforms plugins` (to delete al platforms and plugins) and running `cordova prepare`to restore everything.